# Counterexample of minimum principle in hilbert space on non closed but convex subspace

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

As I mentioned at title, I make tiny counterexample for minimum principle.

> Let $K=C([0,\frac{1}{2}]) \subset H=L^{2}([0,1])$. Then $K$ is convex since every $f,g \in K$, $(\alpha f+(1-\alpha)g)/2$ is also in $K$ for any $0 < \alpha <1$. However $K$ is not closed since not all cauchy sequence is converges; Suppose piecewise continuous function $f_{n} = 1$ if $x < \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}$, $f_{n} = -n(x-\frac{1}{2})$ otherwise. Clearly, $f_{n} \to f=1_{[0,\frac{1}{2})}$, which is not a continuous on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$. However $f$ is in $H$ since $H$ is complete and $\{ f_{n}\} \in H$. Therefor there is no minimum distance point in $C([0,\frac{1}{2}])$ to $f$

Do you think it is reasonable counterexample? Actually I think any characteristic function is in hilbert space since it can be limit point of sequence of continuous function.

Comment: Functions in $H$ are the same if they are equal a.e.. Your limit function is equal a.e. to a function which is continuous on $[0,1/2]$.

Comment: @T.A.E. Thank you for comment, how about change $f_{n} = 1$ if $x < \frac{1}{4}- \frac{1}{n}$, $f_{n} = -n(x-\frac{1}{4})$ if $\frac{1}{4}- \frac{1}{n} \leq x < \frac{1}{4}$, $f_n = 0$ if $x \leq \frac{1}{4}$. Then it converges to $1_{[0,\frac{1}{4})}$ and also discontinuous in almost everywhere sense.

Comment: Why not argue more abstractly. If $K$ a non-closed convex subset of $H$, then there exists $x \in H\setminus K$ which is in the closure of $K$. It follows that there is no $k \in K$ which is closest to $x$ because $\mbox{dist}(K,x)=0$ and $x \notin K$.

Comment: @T.A.E. Oh.. I see. Actually I want to find counter"example" of this, so i didn't think abstractly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize: the example does not work as stated in the question, but can be fixed as stated in a comment:

> change $f_{n} = 1$ if $x < \frac{1}{4}- \frac{1}{n}$, $f_{n} = -n(x-\frac{1}{4})$ if $\frac{1}{4}- \frac{1}{n} \leq x < \frac{1}{4}$, $f_n = 0$ if $x \geq \frac{1}{4}$. Then it converges to $1_{[0,\frac{1}{4})}$ and also discontinuous in almost everywhere sense.

Also, T.A.E.'s comment is worth noting:

> Why not argue more abstractly. If $K$ a non-closed convex subset of $H$, then there exists $x \in H\setminus K$ which is in the closure of $K$. It follows that there is no $k \in K$ which is closest to $x$ because $\mbox{dist}(K,x)=0$ and $x \notin K$.